# What is the font used in the Hot Pockets box (specific area below)

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know the font used here? Trying to make a meme...[image: help pls]

Comment: What font identification methods have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "Warsaw Gothic - Regular".

I have matched the fonts here using this Link: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?token=cz1w1r29p983ditt

You can download the entire font family from here: https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/cannot-into-space-fonts/warsaw-gothic

I have also attached the screenshots of the matched fonts so you can easily compare.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used WhatTheFont Mobile app on an iPhone

Alternate gothic no1
https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/alternate-gothic/no1

I can also see similarities to the font BEBAS NEUE (free) 
You can download it here:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-neue